# Setting a server variable to data held in a mongo collection Meteor.js

Tags: javascript, mongodb, http, meteor, server

For my application, I have to make an HTTP.call to get a session ID. I need to store this session ID into a mongo collection, which I am doing like this.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  sessionDB = new Mongo.Collection("sessionID");
  HTTP.call( 'GET', 'http://mycalltosomeapi.svc/json/whatever', {
  }, function( error, response ) {
if ( error ) {
  console.log(error);
} else {
  sessionDB.insert({
sessionId: response.data.session_id,
date_inserted: new Date()
  });
}
}
```

how do I grab the most recent entry of my mongo stored 'sessionId' and put that into a variable so I can make other calls? I tried doing it like this but had no luck.

```
var sessionId = sessionDB.findOne({}, {sessionId:1}).sort({"date_inserted":-1}).limit(1);
```

Been researching for a couple hours now, can't find anything. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sort` and `limit` are options to [find](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/find) and [findOne](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/findone). Give this a try:

```
var options = {
  fields: {sessionId: 1},
  sort: {date_inserted: -1}
};

var sessionId = sessionDB.findOne({}, options);
```